# htaccess not working in sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

i have a vhosts in ubuntu, i work fine except the .htaccess in a sub-folder (images folder) is not work.

The problem is, I have written a .htaccess file in the sub-folder, and even I typed some thing wrong syntax .htaccess, it does not response error,i am pretty sure that the .htaccess in subfolder is being ignored.
 i think that some setting is needed to let apache beware of the .htaccess in sub-folder, any one can help?

my system is ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Check in the server/vhost config and look for a `<Directory>` container that your images folder is in (or *is* your images folder), something maybe like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhost/images">

</Directory>
```

and inside it, make sure there isn't a:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Change that to either "All" or "FileInfo", depending on what exactly you're overriding in your htaccess file.

Comment: still not work. i add this directive section and seems the .htaccess is still not working, even i add some wrong syntax